# Why the specific index position not working with the .remove?

Tags: python

I'm trying to do the Gradebook python project. For some reason I'm getting value error with specific index. Other index within the array I tried is working fine except for the specific index. Can anyone tell what's wrong with the code :

```
last_semester_gradebook = [
  ["politics", 80],
  ["latin", 96],
  ["dance", 97],
  ["architecture", 65],
]

# list called subjects
subjects = ["physics", "calculus", "poetry", "history"]

# list called grades
grades = [98, 97, 85, 88]

# gradebooks
gradebook = [
  [subjects[0], grades[0]],
  [subjects[1], grades[1]],
  [[subjects[2], grades[2]]],
  [subjects[3], grades[3]],
]

print(gradebook)

# Adding additional grades
gradebook.append(["Computer science", 100])
gradebook.append(["Visual arts", 93])

# adding 5 points
gradebook[-1][-1] = (93 + 5)
print(gradebook)

gradebook.remove(['poetry', 85])
print(gradebook)
```

Other index position works except for 2nd index. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reformatting your code, it becomes somewhat obvious that you're doing something different with the second index:

```
gradebook = [
  [subjects[0], grades[0]],
  [subjects[1], grades[1]],
  [[subjects[2], grades[2]]],
  [subjects[3], grades[3]],
]
```

Presumably it should be:

```
gradebook = [
  [subjects[0], grades[0]],
  [subjects[1], grades[1]],
  [subjects[2], grades[2]],
  [subjects[3], grades[3]],
]
```

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to take the extra bracket out.